# href="javascript:;" or href="javascript:void(0)", the difference?

Tags: javascript, href

I read about the `href="#"` and `href="javascript:void(0)"`comparison,
I also want to know about the comparison about

`href="javascript:;" or href="javascript:void(0)"`,

ps: I use `href="javascript:;"` all the time instead of `href="javascript:void(0)"`,
have not find any trouble.

Comment: Both are bad practices and should be avoided; you're needlessly evaluating JavaScript in the URL bar, which isn't even supported by all browsers. You should be using `href="#"` and intercepting the click with an event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `javascript:` in hyperlinks in either form is bad. Your JavaScript design should be unobtrusive.

If you're going to attach event listeners to your anchors, you should use the `#` anchor or even an actual URL, e.g.:

```
<a href="/delete/post/123">delete</a>
...
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
     $('a').on('click', function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         // do ajax stuff
     });
});
</script>
```

This way, old browsers (or those with JavaScript disabled) will follow a regular link to delete an item whereas JavaScript enabled browsers will do this via AJAX so that the page doesn't have to refresh.

If your link is really meant to do nothing at all, you shouldn't use anchors at all; just style a `<span>` for that purpose.

Comment: it make sense, but still have to pay some price: all the empty links will have a class or something else which is a tag as a empty link.

Answer (score 0):

The usual behaviour for a `javascript:` link is that the document body is replaced with whatever the expression evaluates to, *unless* it evaluates to `undefined`. There is no difference between your two versions, they both evaluate to `undefined` which, in a `javascript:` link, has no effect.

However, this is not the preferred way of making no-op links. Your needlessly forcing the browser to parse and evaluate JavaScript. If you want to make a link which does nothing, you should be setting its `href` to `"#"`, and binding functions to the link's `click` event. Your event handler will be passed an event object; if you want to evaluate some code and then prevent the link from being followed (appending `#` to the currently URL) then you can use `event.preventDefault()`, `event.stopPropagation()`, or simply return `false` from your event handler.

The best option of all is to maintain some meaningful value in your `href` attribute, so that if JavaScript is circumvented (IE, the user opens the link in a new window) there is still some sane fall-back. You should then layer additional "rich" actions *on top* of the existing HTML-only functionality.

Comment: A link with `href="#"` doesn't do nothing, it jumps to the empty bookmark, i.e. the top of the page. That's sooooo annoying.

Comment: @Guffa You should be intercepting the click, as I said. If you want a "link" which *actually* does nothing, you **don't want a link**. You want a div, with `cursor:pointer` applied to it. A link which truly does nothing is not useful in practice.

Comment: @meagar More a `span` than a `div` when juggling with text

Comment: ie6 will not support span:hover, that is the reason span will not take the a's role.unfortunately, someone like me have to support ie6.

Comment: @ZHAOXudong Then you should use span:hover, and ie6 users should not get a pointer cursor on hover. Big deal.

Answer (score 0):

What you put in the `href` is not really relevant. You should stop the link from being followed in the first place, by returning `false` from the click handler.

Example:

```
<a href="fallback.html" onclick="doSomething();return false;">
```

In the `href` you can put a link to a fallback solution for users who have disabled Javascript, or a page informing them that they need Javascript to use the featured of the page.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

javascript:void(0) - more easy to understand, than javascript:some_code_to_execute. Sure, in your case javascript:; is not hard to read, is one will not assume code got broken.

Theres several reason, why handling lcicks with javascript: is bad. I know it's not the actual question, but it's related:

1. This approach is obsolete and as it still supported by browser vendors, it's not in wc3 standards.
2. Link href="javascript" will not work for users without javascript. It's better to use href="/somePage.com?id=123" onclick="makeActionFor(777); return false">
3. No separation between the markup and the code. In this case, putting onclick in prev example is also a bad way to attach click handler.